# строки C-style память

Tags: c++, строки

```
char str[] = "hello";
```

```
const char* str = "hello";
```

я правильно понимаю, что в первом случае выделяется массив из 6 элементов на char на стеке, а во втором случае массив в памяти  для глобальных переменных (сегмент data) и по умолчанию все строковые литералы хранятся там

Comment: В первом случае массив в стеке, если описание **внутри** функции. Если вне, то это глобальный массив в сегменте `.data`. Во втором случае не правильно. Вы получите указатель на память (в общем, конечно, на нуль-терминированный массив), но в сегменте `.rodata` (только для чтения). Попытаетесь изменить и получите exception

Answer (score 1):

Да, правильно.

Хотя теоретически в разных архитектурах все может быть немного по-разному.

Comment: Архитектурах или компиляторах?

Comment: @isnullxbh скорее архитектурах. В рамках одной архитектуры кмпиляторы обычно используют схожие решения. Но, конечно, и тут вариации возможны и неизбежны.